# TestNg Execution is giving warning for POM.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

While executing TestNG runner class I am getting below message on console and TestNG is not launching anything, neither it is showing anything failed.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3 [TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
```

I have tried multiple things like upgrade TestNG from Install Software from eclipse but it didn't work. Below is my pom.xml Also tried to degrade the the TestNG but it didn't work.
Please see the below POM.xml I am using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
      4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>io.testing.tables</groupId>
      <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
     <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
     <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.72</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>   
  
   </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your TestNG XML file. This declaration specifies the TestNG DTD (Document Type Definition) version that should be used. Add the following line at the very beginning of your XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
```

Upgrade the TestNG version in your POM.xml file to a version that supports the TestNG DTD mentioned in the DOCTYPE declaration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

[TestNG ***v6.14.3***](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.14.3) released on Apr 09, 2018 is old and ancient now.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- TestNG is upgraded to recent release of [TestNG **v7.8.0**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/7.8.0):

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- `testng.xml` contains the `DOCTYPE` declaration at the top as:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  ```